# Python continue script after failure

Tags: python, bitbucket-server

I am working with a python api for Atlassian's stash application.

The script fails to delete a project because it has repos inside and then exits.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stash.py", line 38, in <module>
    stash.projects[p["key"]].delete()
  File "<string>", line 2, in delete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stashy/errors.py", line 46, in ok_or_error
    maybe_throw(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stashy/errors.py", line 40, in maybe_throw
    raise e
stashy.errors.GenericException: 409: {u'errors': [{u'message': u'The project "TEST" cannot be deleted because it has repositories.', u'exceptionName': u'com.atlassian.bitbucket.IntegrityException', u'context': None}]}
```

Is it possible to show the error but continue with the script?

Comment: [try-except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called try .. expect pattern or *exception handling* in Python.

In the simplest form:

```
try:
    stash.projects[p["key"]].delete()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

More info:

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html